# Publicize.exe in Post build event command line

Tags: build

Is it possible to call Publicize.exe in Post build event command line?

I have visual studio solution and we are trying to automate the build.

We are facing problems in automating the Unit testing project within the solution as it got accessor files.

We found that using Publicize.exe we can overcome the issue.

Any example commands to call Publicize.exe in Post build event helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CALL "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Publicize.exe" "$(TargetFileName)"